# Timezone setting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set the ActiveRecord's time zone from `UTC` to `current time zone`. This is what I ended up

**Application.rb**

```
module application
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.2
    config.time_zone = 'Tokyo'.freeze
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
  end
end
```

I have turned off the server and restarted and made an object then when I checked the object's `created_at` it seems the ActiveRecords still records the data based on UTC time not `Tokyo` time.

Any solutions guys?

Comment: Do you want change Rails timezone and make AR store time in your local timezone ?

Answer (score 1):

It always records the data of DateTime as `UTC` in Database and it will be converted according to `config.time_zone` if you call `object.created_at`

Let's say, It stored `2018-09-17 04:41:00` or `Fri, 17 Sep 2018 04:41:00 UTC +00:00` in the database.

If your config the timezone as `Tokyo` then the result is `Fri, 17 Sep 2018 13:41:00 JST +09:00`

Additionally, you can use `.in_time_zone` method to convert the DateTime based on that zone. Here's [.in_time_zone](https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/in_time_zone)